# External .js File Breaking when Linked into HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched the forums hoping someone had run into this issue before me, and while I'm sure someone has, they were probably smart enough to fix it themselves.

Here's my issue: when sourcing an external .js file, all javascript inside the script scope breaks.  I'm not sure if there's an issue with how I'm sourcing the script, or if there's an issue in the external file (though I have copied it into the local HTML file and it works fine).  I have searched high and low for an answer and I think I'm at the point where I can't see the forest for the trees.

Here's my external code (banners.js):

```
function randomBanner()
{
    var banners = new Array();
        banners[0] = "\"./images/banner_placholder_L.png\"";
        banners[1] = "\"./images/banner_placholder_R.png\"";

    var ranIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*banners.length);
    return banners[ranIndex];
}
```

Here's the section I am attempting to inject the code:

```
 <!-- BANNER INJECTION -->
 <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <img id="banL" src="./images/banner_placeholder_L.png">
            <script src="banners.js">
                document.write("this");
                //var newBan = randomBanner();
                //document.write(newBan);
                //document.getElementById("banL").src=ranomBanner();
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img id="banR" src="./images/banner_placeholder_R.png">
            <script>
                //document.getElementById("banR").src=randomBanner();
            </script>
        </div>
</div>
```

My folder structure is:

```
./
-index.html
-banners.js
./images/
-banner_placeholder_L.png
-banner_placeholder_R.png
```

I've Googled and oggled all over the internet.  The only thing I can think of is that I'm overlooking some simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure what happened as I had already tried this without success, but moving the  scope to the head and then calling the randomBanner() later in the page seems to work.

However, I now am running into a new issue of the  are not updating.  That however is a different issue.

** Tested by moving banners.js into the head and adding a document.write(randomBanner()) call inside the  below.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like your code structure - far better to have the script inserted only once and then referenced - rather than putting it into the html wherever you expect to use it.

Two issues that may be causing your problem - in your commented out content - you have a typo (ranom not random) - and then the content that you have in your array is faulty - you are escaping quotes into the array - and when the array element is used to update the src - those quotes will cause it to break.

remove the escaped quotes and see if the src attribute updates as expected. You also have typos (presumably) in the array src's ( *placholder* should be *placeholder*)

```
    banners[0] = "./images/banner_placeholder_L.png";
    banners[1] = "./images/banner_placeholder_R.png";
```

also - you can simplify that array as:

```
var banners =["./images/banner_placeholder_L.png","./images/banner_placeholder_R.png"];
```